# Is it possible to run Robot Framework's unittests with Pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, robotframework, pytest, python-unittest

[Robot Framework](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework) has a [great set of unit tests](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/tree/master/utest) which are implemented using Python's [unittest module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). I wonder if these tests can be run with [Pytest](https://pytest.org/) and if somebody has already tried to do so. At least [Pytest's docu says that it can deal with regular Python unittest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#unittest).

EDIT: To be more precise. I would like to run Robot's own over 1000 unit tests with Pytest instead of with Python's unittest module. E.g. now you have to run `python run.py` inside the `utest` folder of RF's repo to execute all unit tests. So what I am actually asking for is **how to modify run.py so that it uses the Pytest framework** instead of the unittest framework?

I think the most tricky part is here:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    docs, vrbst = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    tests = get_tests()
    suite = unittest.TestSuite(tests)
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(descriptions=docs, verbosity=vrbst)
    result = runner.run(suite)
    rc = len(result.failures) + len(result.errors)
    if rc > 250:
        rc = 250
    sys.exit(rc)
```

especially:

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite(tests)
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(descriptions=docs, verbosity=vrbst)
```

I already can run single test by pointing pytest to concrete test file, e.g. `pytest utest/api/test_exposed_api.py`. But if I try to run all unit test in `utest` folder with `pytest utest/` I just get errors and warnings :(

Comment: Are you asking  how to execute pytest from a robot test, or if it's possible for each individual test be run by robot separately? Does the [process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) library do what you want?

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley! No, I just want to use pytest to run Robot's own unit tests. Why? I think pytest is a better (especially more beginner friendly) unit test framework. It could help to ease future contribution to Robot Framework. I'll edit my question to make my intention more clear.

Comment: It may "seem simpler" but I think you should see acceptance tests as a separate beast. Lot's of project use even a different repo to store the acceptance tests. Unit tests test internal stuff, acceptance tests also include tests to ensure that the whole systems works (including external dependencies and external interfaces to other systems). You can use robotframework to test a non python application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes it is! :)))

Long answer: I had to edit only two lines in run.py and was almost happy with the result

1. add `import pytest` below `import unittest`
2. edit the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section so that it looks like that:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       docs, vrbst = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
       tests = get_tests()
       pytest.main()
   ```

Then in utest folder just call `python run.py` and the tests run :)))

```
    1532 passed, 45 warnings, 1 error in 9.70 seconds
```

Obviously there is more stuff which is not necessary for pytest in run.py and could be wiped out ... but me no python expert (yet)